# How do I install ubuntu 14.04 in about 35 GB unallocated space?

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, 14.04, partitioning

I'm using windows 7 and want to run both the OS side by side. Also I do not want to lose any of my files.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. The installation guide is here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall